# Next.js - Dynamically import component library depending on getServerSideProps response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a project with multi-tenancy and want to have the possibility to switch between component libraries based on an external response while keeping SSR.
Both component libraries are having the exact same structure, with the same exported components and accepted props.

Normally, we could do something like this:

```
import * as Components from '@acme/components-old';
    
export default function Page() {   
  return <Components.Button>Some Awesome Button</Components.Button>; 
}
```

Now I want to have something like this (pseudo-code):

```
export default function Page({ components }) {
  import * as Components from '@acme/components-' + components;

  return <Components.Button>Some Awesome Button</Components.Button>;
}

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  return {
    props: {
      components: 'old',
    },
  };
};
```

I'm using styled-components for styling. It seems like I cannot use `next/dynamic` as it does not work with template literals and using a normal import statement also does not work since it requires an async function which seems to break SSR. Also, in the future I'd love to have more than only 2 templates without loading all templates in the client. Unused Templates should be tree-shaken.

Answer (score 0):

You can import both libraries and create a map of your own. As this is on server-side you will only pass to your client what they need.

```
import * as OldComponents from '@acme/components-old';
import * as NewComponents from '@acme/components-new';

const COMPONENT_LIBS_MAP = {
  old: OldComponents,
  new: NewComponents,
}

export default function Page({ components }) {
  const Components = COMPONENT_LIBS_MAP[components];

  return <Components.Button>Some Awesome Button</Components.Button>;
}

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  return {
    props: {
      components: 'old',
    },
  };
};
```